# SOAPEngine's completeWithDictionary is empty

Tags: android, ios, swift, magento

I have this function in Swift iOS using SOAPEngine to get the response:

```
func testLogin() {
    //working url
    var urlString  = "http://192.168.1.3/magento/api/v2_soap/"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var client = SOAPEngine()
    client.userAgent = "SOAPEngine"
    client.actionNamespaceSlash = true
    client.version = VERSION_1_1
    client.setValue("joemar", forKey: "username")
    client.setValue("NewAPIKey", forKey: "apiKey")
    client.setValue("urn:Magento", forKey: "namespace")

    client.requestURL(url, soapAction: "login", completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int, response : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in
        client = SOAPEngine()
        client.userAgent = "SOAPEngine"
        client.actionNamespaceSlash = true
        client.version = VERSION_1_1

        let sessionId : AnyObject? = response

        client.setValue(sessionId, forKey: "sessionId")

        client.requestURL(url, soapAction: "customerCustomerList", completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int, response : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in
            let data : AnyObject? = response
            }, failWithError: { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
            println("failed!")
        })
        }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
        println("failed!")
    }
}
```

However, the 'completeWithDictionary' is always empty. I have used exactly the same function in Android and it was working fine. Android was using ksoap2 library.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the request is valid? Also, does it actually fail or is it empty? (like, do you get error handler, or do you get success with empty object?) Can you provide feed information to see if it is valid?

Comment: Thanks Jiri. Yes the request is valid and it is working on the Android counterpart running on the same backend server. The statusCode was 200 but the response dictionary has 0 key/value pair (success with empty object.) Btw, you will notice that this is a subsequent call to same service with different endpoints. Was able to get the sessionId value on the first call and passed to the next.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `client.responseHeader = true`

a tip: if you want a more immediate support uses the github issues for the SOAPEngine project

Comment: Hi Danilo, thanks. I have moved away from SOAPEngine for the moment as I couldn't fix the issue as it was urgent. I have manually created the SOAP message using AFNetworking instead. Now it is working. I will try again with SOAPEngine if got more time in future projects. Ty.